# Optimal Database Design with a lot of text(active record and postgres)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Model that stores very large amounts of data in a logically nested structure.  The structure of the data is a nested array as follows:

```
A>B>C
```

There are approximately 50k items in A, 200 of B for every A, and 50 C for every B.  Therefore there are 10 million B, and 500 million C. However, Cs are each quite small, normally 2-10 characters of text.

So it seems I have three choices:

```
1.Have one table for A, and store B and C as text in a column in table A
2. Have two tables, one for A and one for B that is associated with A, 
3. Have three tables, one for each of the levels in my hierarchy.
```

I am new to database design so I am not sure which is best.  I'm worried that a 500 million row table will make accessing any entry in that table slow even if properly indexed.  So for example if each of C has an index on b_id, then then searching for all C with a particular b_id will be very slow.

Comment: What is the natura of the relations between A, B and C? One to many?

Comment: Yes one to many so A has many B, B has many C

Comment: I was more interested in the other way round: there is only one B for each C? And only one A for each B?

Comment: Each B can belong to more than one A ?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear.  Yes only one B for each C and only one A for each B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three tables, A, B and C. Postgres will normally handle that just fine... There are much larger Postgres databases than what you describe in the wild; for instance, Skype.

> So for example if each of C has an index on b_id, then then searching for all C with a particular b_id will be very slow.

That will be *fast* if it's properly indexed. Not slow.